# C# Linq Group By Two Statement

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a list. I want to separate the list in pieces by (partionCountValue)variable. And I want to group data by a date value. And the data with the same date must be in the same pieces. I could not group the same date in the same group. How can I do this?

My example code:

```
var list = lstHareket.Select((x,i) => new { Index = i, Value = x})
      .GroupBy(x => x.Index / partionCountValue)

      .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList()

       ).ToList();
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide example values for `lstHareket` and `partitionCountValue` so that others could reproduce your problem, and provide a useful answer. See [mcve] for more help.

Comment: `.Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value)` the predicate inside Select is wrong, you don't need to repeat Select, just x=> some expr

Comment: Some examples of types involved would be great. At the moment you've mentioned a date time property, but we have no idea where this property exists

Comment: You need to specify more about the partitions. Do they have to be full? Or can you group by date and then split any date partition into pieces if it's too large? If they have to be full then what happens if it's not possible to pack them in the way you have requested?

Comment: It is very unclear what you ask for. Why are you dividing by `partionCountValue` in your `GroupBy` statement? You want to group the elements of your list into groups of elements with the same date value. "AND the data with the same date must be in the same pieces" Is a `Piece` the same thing that others would call a `Group`? If you want to group into groups with same Date, why are you grouping by `Index/partionCountValue`? And if you have grouped the data by same date, they are already in the same `Piece`, so what does your AND mean?

Comment: what does "separate the list in pieces" mean?